# Setting the content for each marker Google Maps

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Need a quick help with setting up the content for each marker that I'm creating

I'm looping through my Locations Obj that holds Lat,Lng for each marker (locationObj),
the content for each marker is been hold by other obejct (PermutationObj).

example:

```
 locationObj-- > {"Lat":"34.163291","Lng":"-118.685123"} etc....

 PermutationObj -- > ElectronicPopContent,LocationName
```

The thing is I'm getting for all the markers that I'm displaying on the map the first content and location name from the PermutationObj.

How can I fix it???

JS Code:

```
var locationObj;
        var PermutationObj;
        var map;
        var mapOptions;

        var shape = {
            coord: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18, 1],
            type: 'poly'
        };





      function setMap(locationList, permutation) {
            // List of Lat,Lng
            locationObj = $.parseJSON(locationList);
            PermutationObj = $.parseJSON(permutation);


            var qMapTypeId = google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
            var LatLngCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(34.163291, -118.685123);
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 4,
                center: LatLngCenter,
                mapTypeControl: true,
                mapTypeControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
                }
            }
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            for (i in locationObj) {
                var LatLngPair = new google.maps.LatLng(locationObj[i]["Lat"], locationObj[i]["Lng"]);

                bounds.extend(LatLngPair);
                map.fitBounds(bounds);


//                for (j in PermutationObj) {
//                    //  var image = PropObj[j]["ElectroincImageURL"];
//                    var content = PermutationObj[j]["ElectronicPopContent"];
//                    break
//                }

                var content = PermutationObj[i]["ElectronicPopContent"];

                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: LatLngPair,
                    map: map,
                    draggable: false,
                    //                    icon: image,
                    shape: shape,
                    anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(12, -25)

                });

                //Setting up the content of the info window dynamic wise.
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: content
                });



                //Setting up an event listener, When the user clicks the marker, an info window opens.
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                    infowindow.setContent(content);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think that if you fix the indentation of your code you'll find the problem faster

Comment: I think that the problem should be on the second loop but I'm not sure need second eye to see it

Comment: Also How can I create a click event for each of the markers?!?!

Comment: instead of the second loop use `var content = PermutationObj[i]["ElectronicPopContent"];` and see if it works

Comment: I modified my code like you said and now it giving me only that first content in the object although I'm doing one for loop. btw how can I make all the markers be clickable and not only one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed a few things, the first is having only one instance of the InfoWindow, the other is storing the content as a marker property and use it on the click, the last is having an instance per marker by using `var marker = ...` instead of `marker = ...` Let me know if this works for you.

```
var locationObj;
var PermutationObj;
var map;
var mapOptions;
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ });

var shape = {
    coord: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18, 1],
    type: 'poly'
};

function setMap(locationList, permutation) {
    // List of Lat,Lng
    locationObj = $.parseJSON(locationList);
    PermutationObj = $.parseJSON(permutation);


    var qMapTypeId = google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    var LatLngCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(34.163291, -118.685123);
    var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 4,
            center: LatLngCenter,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
            }
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (i in locationObj) {
        var LatLngPair = new google.maps.LatLng(locationObj[i]["Lat"], locationObj[i]["Lng"]);

        //Are you sure you need these 2 lines here?
        bounds.extend(LatLngPair);
        map.fitBounds(bounds);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: LatLngPair,
            map: map,
            draggable: false,
            shape: shape,
            anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(12, -25),
            infoWindowContent: PermutationObj[i]["ElectronicPopContent"]

        });

        //Setting up an event listener, When the user clicks the marker, an info window opens.
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                infowindow.setContent(marker.infoWindowContent);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }
}
```